# ¿Por qué no puede ver el token string?

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Estoy usando laravel passport pero no puede ver el string del token, les comparto lo que estoy haciendo y quiero saber que me falta.

*PassportAuthController*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PassportAuthController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Login
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ];
 
        if (auth()->attempt($data)) {
            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('LaravelAuthApp')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }   
}
```

*Respuesta Postman*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, el string del token no lo veo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error, yo tenia esto en mi modelo User

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

Lo cambié  por esto; y ya puedo ver el token en la respuesta

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]